# How do i set a watch on an object in ceph?

Tags: c, ceph

I am trying to keep a watch on an object in Ceph, but I don't know how to do it. I searched for examples online but could not find any. Found some documentation [here](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/rados/api/librados/). It says that I can use rados_watch to watch an object for changes. But I dont know how to implement it in C, especially the rados_watchcb_t part. It says rados_watchcb_t would contain the action to execute on notification. How do I declare it?

This is what I tried:

```
rados_watchcb_t rados_watch = printf("Updated");
```

But this gives an error.

Comment: what was your error? Please post it.

Comment: when i run the application, after few seconds it stops working